Exoplayer in ViewPager2: Scrolling video back gives flickering
Scrolling Videos down is working as expected but when the user is going back to view previous video it's showing flickering in video.
Currently, my ViewPager2 extends FragmentStateAdapter and every fragment have their separate Player for them, when scrolling I am releasing the player so possibly because of that my previous videos are flickering.
Other ways I tried but failed

Pausing the video(not releasing) : If I only pause the video and scroll the app is crashing with following exception


java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 88 byte allocation
with 177904 free bytes and 173KB until OOM, target footprint
536870912, growth limit 536870912; giving up on allocation because <1%
of heap free after GC.


Single instance of player:  If I create a single instance of player other video also get played when current video is played, though large heap true is already available inManifest

Note: When a video is loaded, I am checking if a previous video is available and adding it to -1 position from current.
Any help on this is appreciated.
Thanks in advance

Flickering is due to releasing the video player for previous fragments when scrolling. Consider pausing the player instead of releasing it, also need to remove resources associated with the player for fixing OOM and when the fragment becomes visible again then resume playback. Use Lazy Initialization and View Holder Pattern. If you're not already using use ExoPlayer with features like caching, efficient resource management, and lifecycle handling.

https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/867
